# How to analyze UWP application UI freeze?

Tags: user-interface, uwp, freeze

My UWP app goes into UI freeze state sometimes and I don't know why。 I've checked the code about view model and async-await calls.  And I've tried to use the performance profile tool in Visual Studio to get timeline but it only shows the time and duration time about the UI freeze.  I have run out of ideas now.

I tried the dotTrace but it seems that I cannot use it to profile UWP application. Even I " disable the Compile with .NET Native tool chain option in Visual Studio (via the menu Project | Properties... | Build) and rebuild the project."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: If you want, you can contact me (I'm a member of dotTrace team) via submitting support request: https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66771
We'll try to find out what prevents to profile your UWP app with dotTrace.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to use the Visual Studio debugger to find out what the code is doing.

First, make sure that you are set "Debug" mode and that the debugger is going to run on "Local Machine" (there are other options here, but I'm trying to keep things simple).

[image: Visual Studio debug buttons]

Then, click on the "Local Machine" button to run your app using the debugger.

Once your app freezes, click on Debug-Break All:

[image: Debug Break All]

After that, I suggest you use the various Debug commands to further debug your application.

[image: Debug menu items]

For example, you can use the "Call Stack" menu item/window to view what your code is doing.  You can also use the "Threads" menu to see what threads are running.  If you have suspect areas in your code, you might consider adding System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() statements to print out informative messages, and then use the "Output" menu item/window to see what is happening.

If your app first freezes, and then crashes after some time, then this could be because your tasks don't have correct exception handling.  You might consider adding an [UnobservedTaskException handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8) to your code to help you find this problem.

Comment: This is the right answer, should have more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for UI freezing, including code endless loops, asynchronous methods are not handled properly, program errors, etc.

Most of them occur in asynchronous method processing and UI rendering.

1. When calling asynchronous methods, use the `async`/`await` keywords, like:

```cs
//define
public async Task asyncMethod()
{ }

//use
await asyncMethod();
```

2. Reduce resource consumption when rendering a large number of data templates through [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization).

If you have a large list to render, if virtualization is not enabled (referring to controls with virtualization, such as `ListView`), or used, but the conditions of virtualization are destroyed (such as adding `ScrollViewer` outside `ListView` ), This will also cause the UI to freeze and will not return to normal until the list is rendered.

Please check your code for the above problems, or provide a minimal reproducible demo so that we can analyze where the problem occurs.

Best regards.